# using python to access an element's parameter value through RPW

Tags: python, revit-api, pyrevit

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My code is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from rpw import revit, db, ui, DB, UI
import clr

# Import RevitAPI
clr.AddReference("RevitAPI")

dd1 = db.Collector(of_category='Data Devices') 

for d in dd1:
    o=db.Element(d)
    print ("Value of comments parameter = ", o.parameters['Comments'].value)
```

my error message is:

```
File "C:\Program Files\pyRevit-Master\pyrevitlib\rpw\db\parameter.py", line 70, in __getitem__
rpw.exceptions.RpwParameterNotFound: parameter not found [element:2367981]:[param_name:Comments]
```

however I know this parameter is part of every data device element.

Comment: I think the issue is with my collector statement, if I print dd1 I get: 
    <rpw:FamilySymbol [name:WALL] [id:2367981]>

Comment: so it looks like the statement `dd1 = db.Collector(of_category='Data Devices')` is collecting data devices that are instances in the revit model AND instances in FamilyTypes collection?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the line `dd1 = db.Collector(of_category='Data Devices')`to read `dd1 = rpw.db.Collector(of_category='Data Devices', of_class='FamilyInstance')` and that resolved the issue.